# Errors while compiling an OpenGL+OpenCL code on OS X

Tags: macos, opengl, opencl, glut

I am trying to compile an OpenGL+OpenCL code on my Mac and after a lot of efforts managed to get the dependencies installed and understood how to link them (GLUI, GLUT, OpenCL, etc).

Most of the errors are removed but there are 3 errors that still persist as shown below:

```
pranjal:~/parallel-prog$ g++-4.9 mittalp.cpp -fopenmp -framework OpenCL -framework OpenGL -framework GLUI -framework GLUT -w

mittalp.cpp: In function 'void InitCL()':
mittalp.cpp:465:69: error: 'wglGetCurrentContext' was not declared in this scope
   CL_GL_CONTEXT_KHR,  (cl_context_properties) wglGetCurrentContext( ),
                                                                     ^
mittalp.cpp:466:62: error: 'wglGetCurrentDC' was not declared in this scope
   CL_WGL_HDC_KHR,   (cl_context_properties) wglGetCurrentDC( ),
                                                              ^
mittalp.cpp: In function 'void InitGlui()':
mittalp.cpp:619:37: error: 'FALSE' was not declared in this scope
   Glui->add_column_to_panel( panel, FALSE );
                                     ^
```

I tried all compiler flags I knew and wasn't able to compile. The code works well on Windows on a friend's machine but it does not work on my Mac OS X. I am suspecting the errors are because the 3 functions listed in the errors are windows specific. Since I am a new to OpenGL programming, I do not have much knowledge of OS X equivalent functions or what libraries are needed on my Mac to make these windows specific functions work.

I have added the C++ code [here](http://pastebin.com/5df0chCX) for reference:

Comment: If you want to create platform independent project then I would suggest to use a library like glfw, which will create an abtraction layer over the platform dependent function like `wglGetCurrentContext`, `glxGetCurrentContext`  and `CGLGetCurrentContext`

Comment: @t.niese: I downloaded and installed glfw. Can you please tell me what are the equivalent functions that I need to use instead of the above platform dependent functions? (or do I need to make more changes than just that?)

Comment: glfw does not provide _equivalent_ functions, then can be used as direct replacement, they create an abstraction layer wrapping the platform specific functions to create a platform independent api. There is a simple  [example code](http://www.glfw.org/documentation.html) for the opengl part on the glfw page, and a [getting started](http://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/quick.html) page explaining the _main_ functions.

Comment: @t.niese Do I have to replace glut entirely with glfw then in my code [1]? That looks like a lot of changes. No option to make wglGetCurrentContext somehow work in Mac as well?
 [1] http://pastebin.com/5df0chCX

Comment: You would need to use `CGLGetCurrentContext` and `CGLGetShareGroup` but you need to look up the usage yourself, because I don't know the correct usage by heart. I always try to avoid to use those platform specific functions directly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's the code that I use for initialising the OpenCL context properties to enable OpenGL interoperability on Windows, OS X and Linux:

```
#if defined(_WIN32)

    // Windows                                                                  
    cl_context_properties properties[] = {
      CL_GL_CONTEXT_KHR, (cl_context_properties)wglGetCurrentContext(),
      CL_WGL_HDC_KHR, (cl_context_properties)wglGetCurrentDC(),
      CL_CONTEXT_PLATFORM, (cl_context_properties)platform,
      0
    };

#elif defined(__APPLE__)

    // OS X                                                                     
    CGLContextObj     kCGLContext     = CGLGetCurrentContext();
    CGLShareGroupObj  kCGLShareGroup  = CGLGetShareGroup(kCGLContext);

    cl_context_properties properties[] = {
      CL_CONTEXT_PROPERTY_USE_CGL_SHAREGROUP_APPLE,
      (cl_context_properties) kCGLShareGroup,
      0
    };

#else

    // Linux                                                                    
    cl_context_properties properties[] = {
      CL_GL_CONTEXT_KHR, (cl_context_properties)glXGetCurrentContext(),
      CL_GLX_DISPLAY_KHR, (cl_context_properties)glXGetCurrentDisplay(),
      CL_CONTEXT_PLATFORM, (cl_context_properties)platform,
      0
    };

#endif
```

Comment: I took long time yesterday night to figure out all this and now I got an answer from you as well. :) Thanks! I also had to include the follo. line  `#pragma OPENCL EXTENSION CL_APPLE_gl_sharing : enable` other than this.

Comment: As of 2021, this answer doesn't solve the problem